# How to make sure a trade is executed with binance python

Tags: python, api, binance

I need to sell my coins when the algorithm takes the decision. But if i create an order of sell and then the price drops, obviously no one will buy at that price. Therefore I need to check if the order is filled and if it is not I need to redo the order. (Maybe there is a better solution to that I'm open to all kinds of answers)

Here is my try at it : (it will sometimes do the upper scenario and execute the code after this part with an order which was not executed yet which will make the program crash).

```
        #sellOrder
        sellOrder = client.create_order(symbol = hparams['MARKET_STRING'], side = 'SELL', type = 'MARKET', quantity = hparams['TRADE_TOKEN_AMOUNT'])
        print("Selling ...")
        print(sellOrder)
        sellOrderID = sellOrder['orderId']
        time.sleep(30)
        soldCheck = True
        while soldCheck:
            currentOrder = client.get_order(symbol = hparams['MARKET_STRING'], orderId = sellOrderID)
            if currentOrder['status'] == 'FILLED':
                soldCheck = False
            else:
                #cancel orber 
                client.cancel_order(symbol = hparams['MARKET_STRING'], orderId = sellOrderID)
                time.sleep(1)
                sellOrder = client.create_order(symbol = hparams['MARKET_STRING'], side = 'SELL', type = 'MARKET', quantity = hparams['TRADE_TOKEN_AMOUNT'])
                sellOrderID = sellOrder['orderId']
                time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you using contradicting logic in your while loop.

If I've understood correctly, you've run into an issue with executing the code that is within the loop?

The syntax `while SoldCheck:` will run a loop while the boolean variable SoldCheck is True - you have set this statically to False, so the loop will not run.

Try this:

```
#sellingorder
sellOrder = client.create_order(symbol = "DOGEEUR", side = 'SELL', type = 'MARKET', quantity = float(50.0))
print("Selling ...")
print(sellOrder)
sellOrderID = sellOrder['orderId']

time.sleep(5) #sleeping while it sells
#Check order was sold TODO
soldCheck = True #true = not sold TODO
while soldCheck:
    currentOrder = client.get_order(symbol = "DOGEEUR", orderId = sellOrderID)
    if currentOrder['status'] == "FILLED":
        soldCheck = False #sold
    else:
        #cancel order
        client.cancel_order(symbol = "DOGEEUR", orderId = sellOrderID)
        time.sleep(1)
        sellOrder = client.create_order(symbol = "DOGEEUR", side = 'SELL', type = 'MARKET', quantity = float(50.0))
        sellOrderID = sellOrder['orderId']
        time.sleep(5)
```

Then, when the if condition is satisfied (i.e. status filled) then you are reverting the SoldCheck flag to False to stop the loop as you no longer need to cancel the order.

If the above solved your issue, please can you accept the answer? If i think of a better way to do it i'll add to here, but the above should solve your problem.

EDIT: You are attempting to place a MARKET order, which by definition is not affected by price fluctuations in the same way as LIMIT. A Market order means that you TAKE the best price the market is willing to give you - this trade should be filled immediately.

If error is within the given function (hard to say without detail on how this function is called) I believe it is one of:

1. status of currentOrder when it is a market order is not set to 'Filled' and as such the loop is never exiting.
2. the cancel order call is not cancelling the original order as it is already filled, but you dont check if the order got successfully cancelled before attempting to place another.

To help understand the issue, could you please provide the output from original create_order call, get_order call and cancel_order?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Calleb, this is my bad here i copy pasted an old version from the code, but I already noticed this, and changed soldCheck init to True. I am still getting errors from that loop.

Comment: The behaviour is that it will sell the coins, and then try to sell them again which will result in an impossible move because my account balance is too low (coins already sold)

Comment: could you paste the full output when you run the code and get the error exception?

Comment: you might consider basing the cancellation and re-placing on price fluctuation rather than elapsed time since placing. Implement a method that gets the last market price for the coin and check if price has gone down since placing, if it goes down by a certain amount, you want to cancel the old one and place a new one for a lower price to ensure you get in.

Comment: Sorry, just realised the trade you are trying to place is a Market type - this means you take the market price rather than set your own - in which case your trade should never fail to 'Fill'. Could you provide the output of currentOrder (i.e. the return when called)? Either the if condition isnt being satisfied and the loop isnt being exited, or the whole method is being called again outside sell order function.

Comment: if you could also show the code that is executed after the trade is placed would be helpful to identify the error, i.e. the code that calls on this function

Comment: I have solved the error, it actually was coming from a copy paste indenting fail ... Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Glad to hear it was resolved!